# How to judge user close the push notification or delete the app

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

My test app can receive apple push notification and my server saves the user's token in database.

I want to know how to judge user close the push notification or delete the my app, then I can via webservice delete the user's info, so it can reduce server pressure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you will not be able to detect when a user dismisses the push notification dialog.  But you can pull the APNS Feedback Service for inactive/uninstalled devices.

You can read up on how the Feedback Service works toward the end of [this documentations.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3)